# How to embed 3d input in keras?

Tags: keras, 3d, reshape, embedding, batchsize

I am trying to make an `Embedding` layer in Keras.

My input size is 3d: `(batch, 8, 6)`, and I want to have an embedding for the last dimension.
So the embedding should work as `(batch*8, 6)` -> `embedding output`

But I don't want to keep this `batchsize` for all the learning step, just for the embedding layer.

I think one of the solution is seperating 8 inputs and applying the embedding to each input.
But then this embedding layer is not the same as one big embedding layer.

Is there any possible solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple:

```
input_shape = (8,6)
```

And pass through embedding. You will get exactly what you want.

---

### A complete working example:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *

ins = Input((8,6))
out = Embedding(10, 15)(ins)
model = Model(ins, out)
model.summary()
```

Where 10 is the dictionary size (number of words or similars) and 15 is the embedding size (the resulting dimension).

Resulting summary:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 8, 6)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 8, 6, 15)          150       
=================================================================
Total params: 150
Trainable params: 150
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thanks! but I want to embed with last dimension(only 6), is this solution embed with (8,6) dimension?

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. It will become `(batch, 8, 6, embedding_size)`.

Comment: I try but the sol does not work. I want to use input_length as 6. Is it impossible?

Comment: You don't need `input_length`, this argument is sort of useless in my view. Just don't use it. See the updated answer for a working example.

Comment: Maybe you think that the 8 and the 6 are separate things? No, they are just how the values are "distributed", but you can't get values from the 6 without getting values from the 8, that doesn't exist. (Operations that work on specific axes are "reduction" ops, operations that sum a dimension, or take a mean, or the maximum argument, etc. But an embedding is not like that, it just takes all values, and for each value returns a vector. There isn't any reduction or dimension specific operation, so, there is no axis distinction in am embedding, it just keeps the same original distribution).